# How to fixed the Out of Memory Error for java8

Tags: java-8, out-of-memory, java

everyone:

My service occured OOM Exception very often,the error message like this:

```
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007f3f6e360000, 65536, 1) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
    #
    # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
    # Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 65536 bytes for committing reserved memory.
```

My server's JDK version:

```
    java -version
    openjdk version "1.8.0_121"
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-8u121-b13-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b13)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

My server's memory info:

```
  free -m
                  total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
    Mem:           3951         515        3107           0         328        3197
    Swap:          4095        1067        3028
```

my service's start shell is like this:

```
    nohup java -Xmx2048m -Xms1024m -jar  myService.jar >nohup.out &
```

the service is running ok on my local computer；
but when i deploy the service for my cloud server， the error has happend！

my local computer's memory is 4G; 
my cloud server's memory is also 4G, and swap memory is 4G;

anyone can help me? 
very very thanks!!!

Comment: Find what is using that memory and see if you can't optimize that...

Comment: That probably means your server is eating a lot of memory, and there may be problems with memoryleaks. Have [the JVM write a heapdump file on OOM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/clopts001.html) and inspect that file using a tool  like Eclipse MAT.

Comment: when i start the service， and see the used memory by "free -m", i can found the server also have a lot of memory.

Answer (score 1):

User a profiling tool like jvisualvm and find out what uses your memory. Then either fix that or give your JVM enough memory.

Comment: the service running on my local computer is ok; but deploy on the VM server, has occured oom error. i think the server's memory is enough。

Comment: Then you probably misconfigured your VM (not enough memory) or used a 32-bit version of Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the application with option **-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=55m**

The default value for the same is *ZERO* (default in Java 7&8 is 0)

Comment: I add the option -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=200m, but also have error, the commond like this:  nohup java -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=200m -jar  myService.jar >nohup.out &